# Delay registering pressed/ repeated key on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have a new X1 Carbon with Windows 10, and when I try to press a key now and keep it depressed to have repeated keys, there's a bit of a delay before it actually starts to work.

It feels like Filter keys is turned on, even though I have that option disabled.

My previous computer was an X1 carbon as well, and it didn't have this issue.

Does anyone know if there's a way I could adjust/ change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in the start menu for `Keyboard Properties` and open it. Go to `Speed` tab and select a shorter `Repeat Delay`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I actually had the problem locating "Keyboard Properties" in start menu. I ended up having to open "Control Panel" and click on "Keyboard".

Comment: This setting keeps getting reverted for me. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Probably an application changes the settings. google your issue and [check this](https://superuser.com/questions/1077223/windows-10-keyboard-repeat-rate-delay-keeps-changing)